# How to manage Azure Backup with Azure Python SDK or Azure Cli

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Basically the title is the question, there are no ways to interact with backup services in the Azure Cli and\or Azure Python SDK (unless I'm missing something), so how do I manage that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the feature request link above](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2384), azure backup support has been merged and will be available in the next (as of Sept 21, 2017) version of the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Backup currently doesn't support python SDK or Azure CLI. You can use REST API or powershell.

Feature request:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2384

Comment: any eta on that? what about Cli2?

Comment: Open an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli and drop the link in this post please :)

Comment: You can also ask in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python because anyway the SDK needs to publish before the CLI2 commands.